# Is encoding an image in base64 make svg <image> load synchronously?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, browser, svg

I have an `<image>` svg that is generated by another system.
My goal is to popup the print dialog box once all the images and font files have been rendered onto a new window.

I have tried a lot of methods and found out that the browsers don't implement the svg w3 standard properly, for example I tried the code below using images that are called with a url but the 'onload' event fires sporadically.
Some obscure answer said it's because the browser caches the images, so I tried appending random query strings to the image; that did not work either.

I tried everything under the sun, now I am trying to embed a base64 image into the file and see if it forces the browser to load the image synchronously?

Question is, is it possible to force the browser to render the image first by using base64 image? I care mostly for the Chrome browser.

```js
var svgFile = `<svg>
<image externalResourcesRequired="true" id="testImage" x="-600" y="2040" height="100px" width="100px" xlink:href=""/>
</svg>`;


var win = window.open();

win.document.write('<style type="text/css">body{margin: 0;padding: 0}  </style>');
    win.document.write('<style type="text/css" media="print">@page {size: auto; margin: 0mm;}</style>');
win.document.write(svgFile);


var testImage = win.document.getElementById('testImage');

testImage.onload = function () { //after image is fully loaded
  win.focus(); //necessary for IE >= 10
  win.print();
  win.close();
  return true;
}

var imageInBase64 = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAA...';
testImage.setAttribute('xlink:href', imageInBase64);
```

I also tried the code below to see if the rendering catches up with javascript execution (put it in the event queue), but it does not seem to work.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
   win.focus(); //necessary for IE >= 10
   win.print();
   win.close();
   return true;
}, 0);
```

Another thing, I read somewhere that the onload event does not fire for generated svg code unless it is parsed by the browser directly.

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is due to using 'document.write'. I'm having trouble switching thinking gears to tell you why but I'm sure someone else will.

Comment: For `img` tags this is not possible, so I assume the same is true for xlinks. Although I think some older versions of Chrome would perform this synchronously, this behavior should not be expected.

Comment: i would just wait a few hundred ms in a setTimeout around your last 9 or 10 lines, after the document.write() part. or use a window.onload on the popup.

Comment: @dandavis problem with waiting a few milliseconds is the rendering might not be done by the time the event fires for a lot of different reasons, specially if I am fetching data from an external source. unfortunately the window.onload event does not fire at all, might have something to do with a generated code instead of a parsed svg code

Comment: the rendering doesn't need to be done, and in fact should NOT be done, or else you'll miss the img.onload event. all you need is for the popup's DOM to be complete, and that should happen quickly. it's just that when you look immediately after the write(), it's not there yet. you might also want a more valid html shell page to write(), to avoid quirks from implicit <body> tags.

Comment: @dandavis so by the time I print the window, all images will be rendered? if so is that always a guarantee 100% of the time?

Comment: well, you will have to wait on external stuff to come in, but you should at least be able to subscribe to those resources' load/readystatechange/etc events within a few ms of the popup being write()en, and once all those events fire, you can print perfectly.

Comment: @dandavis I wanted the guarantee because some of the code will be deployed into old systems and I don't want to assume the time the it takes to render, do you know if the rendering of a base64image is synchronous? or should I not assume that

Comment: no, it's not sync. it's quick, but not sync; wait on the onload events. the short dom parsing delay is pretty safe to assume with under. say, 10kb of tag markup